# Add Collection group with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ancestry

Iam using [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) with location model. If user select parent how display children, then click children display siblings?

How can apply in user _form.html.erb?

[image]

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_ancestry :cache_depth => true
 has_many :users
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ancestry**

The process would be relatively simple, considering `ancestry` gives you a series of methods to achieve this:

[image]

What you'll want to do is create an `on change` function in javascript to pass the relative object through to your controller, which it will return the results you need:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :locations do
   get :siblings
end

#app/controllers/locations_controller.rb
Class LocationsController < ApplicationController
   repsond_to :json, only: :siblings

   def siblings
      @location = Location.find params[:id]
      respond_with @location.children #-> might need some logic to differentiate between siblings / children
   end
end
```

This will allow you to define ajax methods to manage the response from the data:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "#your_select", function(){
   var id = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
      url: "/locations/" + id + "/siblings",
      dataTye: "json",
      success: function(data) {
          // append result to your other select boxes
      }      
   });
});
```

This should provide you with the functionality you need